# Why doesn't winform open without Application.Run()?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, program-entry-point

I tried to show a winform with the code below but it opens and immediately closes.
I couldn't understand the reason for this.Any ideas?

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AllUnhandledExceptions;
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);

            Test testWin = new Test();
            testWin.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Main : " + ex.Message, typeof(Program));
        }
    }
```

Its works fine if I replace testWind.Show() with Application.Run(testWin).

Comment: It "opens" just fine, there's just no way to see it since the program terminates a microsecond later.  Application.Run() is a hard requirement in GUI apps, it solves the [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).  The producer is the operating system, the consumer is your UI.  You don't consume anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Run` runs the message loop which basically handles UI events etc until all the visible windows have shut. The method blocks until the message loop has shut down.

You need that message loop to be running in order to keep the UI up, basically - whereas `Show()` will just display the window, but not run any kind of message loop itself, and not block - do the `Main` method completes, and the application terminates.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ShowDialog` method instead.

```
Test testWin = new Test();
testWin.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: It is actually working, but it is opening and closing immediately